# How can i access my company's network from a Client Virtual Machine, when at home

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

Here i the scenario:

1. I am using MacbookPro as host
2. Using VBox for creating / using VM's
3. Using ubuntu as VM , with the installed software which needs access to my work (over VPN, of course)
4. Have VPN Connectivity from Mac, and able to ssh to hosts @ work

I am unable to access the same hosts when logged in to the VM on my Mac.

The company network is 10.x.x. (as the case with most companies)
I am using comcast at home, which defaults to a 192.168.x.x type of address

When using the same setup @ work, i am able to have access to work computers , but not when i am at home. Any clues to what i need to do to get access from within a VM?.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since the VM instance is an entirely separate system I don't think you are going to be able to do this, as the Mac has no knowledge of the VPN that you are connected to.

You might ask this over on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/) as well, it might get more answers.